# How to remove unwanted commas and hyphenate between words in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a huge column of data and I need to edit and remove the commas, brackets and hyphen in column 1 and edit it as given in column 2 below.

example

```
column1
```

airline,-airport-and-aviation-management-(including-foundation-year)---bsc-(hons)
airline,-airport-and-aviation-management---bsc-(hons)

The exected result should be as below

```
   column2 
    
    airline-airport-and-aviation-management-including-foundation-year-bsc-hons
    airline-airport-and-aviation-management-bsc-hons
```

Comment: You can nest a couple of SUBSTITUTE functions: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"---","-"),",",""),"(","")` ETC.

Comment: Thank you, It helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sheet couple of soln(s) for you ([here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9633dyScQSQFJRHij?e=jyRMPp)/screenshot below) refers

[image: Excel function]

This is using:

[image: VB function]

```
Function Compress(str As String, Optional BadChars As String = ",#.-&+@'~`[]{}<>/\|()")
##Remove default and custom chars..
##Adapted by 007-JB (01 07 21)
    Dim Ch As Long
    If Len(BadChars) <> 0 Then
        For Ch = 1 To Len(BadChars)
            str = Replace(str, Mid(BadChars, Ch, 1), "")
        Next Ch
    End If
    Compress = str
End Function
```

Comment: @Balash: Consider upvoting/downvoting to help future users.